# Is there a way to use Skype chat from within the browser?

Tags: chat, skype-for-web

Is there a way to use Skype's chat features from within the browser?

It would be great to be able to converse with your contact in situations where you can't necessarily install applications (while traveling, using others computers, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've heard of [Imo.im](https://imo.im/) but have never tried it.

Comment: In my experience we had problems with imo.im and conferences (more than 2 people chatting)

Comment: imo.im is probably limited in some ways (haven't tried it). The question of why Skype doesn't allow users to log into a secured site in order to chat/msg/call from there with almost any computer/phone system is allover the www. Maybe Skype should have been Google.
Or is it?
Not.
It seems Microsoft has bought it..
After Ebay.
The hell, who knows who buys who these days as everyone seems to buy everyone else ;-)
What a world.

Comment: Imo.im has recently disabled skype.

Comment: @user39587 Since imo.im cut their skype support this answer is outdated, but https://plus.im/ supports skype too.